# Slicing QuerySet with [n:] and [n: end] gives different results when using .values_list()

Tags: python, django

In pure python, `[n:]` and `[n: len(mylist)]` are equivalent. However it is not true with Django `QuerySet`.

I ran into this issue:

```
# ci is a QuerySet
In [88]: id_name_value = list(ci[ci.count() - 1000:].values_list("id", "attributes__name", "attributes__value"))

In [89]: len(id_name_value)
Out[89]: 7254

In [90]: id_name_value = list(ci[ci.count() - 1000 : ci.count()].values_list("id", "attributes__name", "attributes__value"))

In [91]: len(id_name_value)
Out[91]: 1000
```

Where the behaviour is clearly not the same. In this case `[n: QuerySet.count()]` gives me what I want, and `[n:]` does something else, but what does it do?

**Edit:**

The items that I get from:

```
In [4]: temp = ci[ci.count()-1000:]

# and 

In [6]: temp_2 = ci[ci.count()-1000: ci.count()]
```

are the same, the difference shows up when I apply `.values_list()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is that you are fetching values from a related model attributes.

```
values_list("id", "attributes__name", "attributes__value")
```

That means that ids will be duplicated in the results. Each id will appear once for each related attribute.

You therefore get lists of two different lengths, because `ci.count()` (the number of unique ids) is not the same as the length of the values queryset (which has duplicates).

To get the last 1000 values of the values queryset, you could do:

```
ci[ci.values_list("id", "attributes_name", "attributes_value").count() - 1000:].values_list("id", "attributes__name", "attributes__value"))
```

or

```
ci.reverse()[:1000].values_list("id", "attributes__name", "attributes__value")
```

Note that the second queryset will have the items in reverse order.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but  I am still not seeing why `ci[ci.count() - 1000:]` and `ci[ci.count() - 1000 : ci.count()` lead to different results after `.values_list()` is applied. I am using `ci.count()` to slice `ci`, why does what happens after that when I apply `.values_list()` matter?

Comment: You aren't actually slicing `ci`, you're slicing the final queryset. `ci.values_list(...)[x:]` will generate the same result as `ci[x:].values_list(...)`. The values queryset has more entries than ci because of duplicates. Comparing the lengths after slicing with of `[ci.count() - 1000:]` and `[ci.count() - 1000:ci.count()]` is not the same as comparing the results for `[n:]` and `[n: len(mylist)]`, because the length of the values queryset is not equal to `ci.count()`.

Answer (score 1):

If you do `qs[n:]` then it'll give you the last `n` objects, and the reverse `[:n]` gives you the first `n` objects.

Furthermore, if you do `qs[o:l]` then `o` is an offset and `l` is a limit.

For example `qs = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]`

```
first = qs[:3]
# first == [0, 1, 2]

last = qs[3:]
# last == [7, 8, 9]

offset = qs[2:6]
# offset = [3, 4, 5]
```

These can be found in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/queries/#limiting-querysets) for limiting a queryset.

Comment: "If you do qs[n:] then it'll give you the last n", that's last `qs.count() - n` elements, right?

Comment: `qs.count() - n` would be what was left over because you're getting a new queryset of the final `n` elements from the original queryset.

Comment: @Akavall what do you get if you just call `.values_list('id', flat=True)`

Comment: If I do `temp = ci[ci.count() - 1000:].values_list("id", flat=True)`, I get a `ValuesListQuerySet`, and `temp.count()` == 1000.

Comment: So it is not really `.values_list()` where the problem (issue) shows up, but when `"attributes__name", "attributes__value"` are involved.

Comment: This answer is incorrect: `qs[n:]` will give you `(length_of_qs - n)` elements, not `n` elements. `a_list[-n:]` would give you the last `n` elements, but querysets do not support negative indexing.